# LocalTime parsing with AM/PM

Tags: java, datetime

I have a time string coming from another source in format "hh:mma", for example, 10:00a or 07:30p. I need to create an instance of `LocalTime` from that string. I've tried to parse it by calling the method:
`LocalTime.parse("10:00p", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mma"))`, but it throws an `DateTimeParseException`. In accordance with [DateTimeFormatter API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), part of the time should be in uppercase and consist of 2 letters (PM instead of p). But is there any method to parse time without changing the sourse line?

Comment: Can you share your code

Comment: @fiskra The code is already there, inlined in the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But is there any method to parse time without changing the sourse
>   line?

Yes, this formatter can do that for you:

```
    Map<Long, String> ampmStrings = Map.of(0L, "a", 1L, "p");
    DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("hh:mm")
            .appendText(ChronoField.AMPM_OF_DAY, ampmStrings)
            .toFormatter();
```

With `DateTimeFormatterBuilder.appendText` we can define our own texts for both formatting and parsing. I used the Java 9+ `Map.of` to initialize a map of two key-value pairs. If you are using Java 6, 7 or 8, I trust you to initialize the map differently. The rest should still work.

Let’s try it out:

```
    String sourceLine = "10:00a";
    LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(sourceLine, timeFormatter);
    System.out.println("Parsed time: " + time);
```

Output is:

> Parsed time: 10:00

A yet better option would be if you could persuade your source to provide strings in [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (like `10:00` and `19:30`).

Answer (score 3):

Replace `p` with `PM`, `a` with `AM`, then parse it with pattern `hh:mm a`.

```
String time = "10:00p";
time = time.replace("p", "PM").replace("a", "AM"); // 10:00PM
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse(time, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a", Locale.US));
System.out.println(localTime); // 22:00
```

Comment: May work, but you should point to your `Locale.US` which is unlikely to produce the desired output in Belarus in every case. Maybe `Locale.getDefault()` would be a better option.

Comment: @deHaar It's used to recognize `AM` and `PM`, not for formatting.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I asked is it possible to parse string without any changes to it